# printing a texture2D to file or as image for debugging purposes

Tags: c#, android, image, unity-game-engine, texture2d

I am trying to figure out how an image is processed (what it looks like, etc...) at several stages of Image Processing operations, so I have written the following `co-routine` to capture a screenshot, but I am not sure how to **print out** the taken shots at different stages (for example as **png images**)

```
public void CaptureFrame(RectTransform rect)
{
    StartCoroutine( Co_Capture(rect) );
}

private IEnumerator Co_Capture(RectTransform rect)
{
    yield return new WaitForEndOfFrame();

    _texture = new Texture2D( (int)rect.sizeDelta.x, (int)rect.sizeDelta.y );
    _texture.ReadPixels( new Rect( rect.anchoredPosition.x - (rect.sizeDelta.x * 0.5f), rect.anchoredPosition.y - (rect.sizeDelta.y * 0.5f), rect.sizeDelta.x, rect.sizeDelta.y ), 0, 0 );
    _texture.Apply();

    OnImageCaptured( new ScreenShotEventArgs(_texture) );
}
```

Given that I build the app to an **Android** device, ideally I would like to have the images saved both in a folder somewhere (through **Unity3D Editor**) as well as on the device in its `data` folder, for example. Something akin to `Debug.Log` messages that you print out at different stages to see which parts of your code are reached, etc...

What options do I have? What is the code/command/method for saving an image/picture through Unity3D and also on an Android tablet, so that the developer can see the images at various stages or processing?

Comment: The title and body are both confusing. Print image??  To me, it just looks like you want to take a screenshot then save it and then later load it. Is that so?

Comment: @Programmer Yes, exactly. I figured out I should use `byte[] debugImage1 = _texture.EncodeToPNG();` and then `File.WriteAllBytes(Application.dataPath + "/../Img1.png", debugImage1);` Would you agree? Is there a better alternative? Basically, I am trying to see what Tesseract does to an image before it recognises its text, so I need to see the outcome of various image-processing steps of Tess.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You got some of it right in the comment section. You use `EncodeToPNG()` to convert it to a byte array then save it with `File.WriteAllBytes`. What you **didn't** get right is the path.

You use save to `Application.persistentDataPath` if you want that to work on Android, iOS and any platform. It is a must to save it in a folder instead of directly saving it to `Application.persistentDataPath`.

So that should be `Application.persistentDataPath+"/yourfoldername/imagename.png"`.

Again, this: `Application.persistentDataPath+"/imagename.png"` will fail on iOS because you are trying to write directly to the sandbox which requires a folder like I mentioned above.

Finally, I noticed you are using `+` to concatenate paths. Avoid doing that and instead use `Path.Combine`.

```
string tempPath = Path.Combine(Application.persistentDataPath, "yourfoldername");
tempPath = Path.Combine(tempPath, "yourfoldername.png");
```

Answer (score 0):

This will save the texture as Img1.png at a valid, public location on all devices.

```
File.WriteAllBytes(Path.Combine(Application.persistentDataPath + "Img1.png"), _texture.EncodeToPng());
```